# Как использовать OAuth 2.0 (Google) в клиент-серверном приложении?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth2

**Имеется клиент-серверное приложение,клиент это android-приложение ,а сервер это asp.net core web api.**

**Цель**: проверять на подлинность запросы клиента к моему api, т.е. удостовериться,что у данного юзера есть права на данный запрос.

**Вопросы:**

1. Как использовать OAuth 2.0 (Google) в данном случае(какое разделение
   логики требуется)?
2. Что должен отправлять клиент к API?
3. Как api должно проверять приходящий запрос?

Хотелось бы ссылок на материал/ы или полноценного ответа

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth